# iOS Certificate Pinning and Amazon Certificate Manager

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I can't find good information regarding certificate pinning in iOS and Amazon Certificate Manager.

They recommend you don't pin against an ACM certificate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-bestpractices.html#best-practices-pinning

> We recommend that your application not pin an ACM Certificate

The reason they don't recommend it is that:

> To renew a certificate, ACM generates a new public-private key pair.

Instead, they recommend:

> If you're using a public certificate, pin your application to all available Amazon root certificates.

I understand why **not to pin** to an ACM Certificate - because you will have to release updates with new certificates risking possible bricking of clients. You also can't pin against the public key because it will change.

What I don't understand is how pinning against only the root certificates is ok? Will it still prevent man in the middle attacks? How is this more secure?

Can someone explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be more secured to pin against the root certificate. I think what the Amazon documentation trying to recommend is a way that would not break your network connection in the case that when the certificate expires and renews.

Here's the quote from this website explaining the different kinds of certificate pinning: 
https://carvesystems.com/news/cert_pin/

> Leaf Cert: A leaf cert is the top level cert in a certificate chain.
>   Pinning a leaf certs brings us to almost complete certainty that the
>   certificate matches. However, if you cycle your leaf certs often,
>   updates need to roll out fairly frequently to make sure your
>   customer’s app continues to work.
>
> Intermediate Cert: The intermediate cert lives between the leaf and
>   root cert. In this case, pinning against the intermediate cert, you’re
>   putting your trust in the intermediate certificate authority.
>   Therefore, you can update your server’s leaf cert more often, as the
>   validation of certs occurs on the intermediate cert.
>
> Root Cert: Finally, the root cert comes from the trusted certificate
>   authority. Pinning the root cert alone puts trust in the root cert
>   authority, as well as all intermediaries that the root cert authority
>   trusts.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.